# Continuity and divergence

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Put
\begin{equation}
F(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1}a_{n}(s),
\end{equation}
where $a_{n}(s) \geq 0$ for **all** $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and
the series converges for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$.

Suppose that $F(s)$ is analytic for $\text{Re}(s) > 0$.

If we know that the series expression for $F(s)$
becomes $+\infty$ for some point $s \in (0, 1)$,
then could we conclude that $F(s)$ has a singularity
for some positive real number s?

In case that F is a Dirichlet series, the answer
may be affirmative (it may be called Landau's theorem).

My guess is that F should have a singularity,
since F is known to be analytic (that is, continuous),
but I have no rigorous argument to show it.

Thanks for reading.